# How should I format this MySQL query for PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this neat-o MySQL query in my PHP script. All the variables in it are already declared in the program, the connection is activated earlier in the program, and when I run it in a MySQL prompt with the variables subbed for proper values, it runs. The data types are TEXT, TEXT, TEXT and DATETIME respectively.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO julian.guestbook (name, message, email, date) VALUES ($_POST[\'name\'], $newmsg, $newmail, NOW()");
```

I feel like it's probably a syntax issue, but I have no clue what it is. Can anyone help?

Comment: `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`. syntax error is in your values

Comment: you don't need to escape the single quotes in $_POST['name']